# ASP.Net Authentication and Authorization options

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have the usual requirement of implementing Authentication and Authorization. I used to implement it using custom code where I have Users, Roles, Role_Pages, User_Pages, and User_Roles. So this way we can give a certain user roles (that group multiple pages) and/or directly define access to certain pages. All that with the ability to specify fine grained permissions like the ability to Add/Edit/Delete records in those pages.

My question: How easy is it to implement this using Forms Authentication and what advantage does that give over implementing a custom solution. I am also concerned with knowing if there would be any advantage when it comes to securing from session hijacking and against spoofing where an attacker could replay requests and impersonate legit users. Would Forms Authentication have any advantage there, or is it only SSL that can secure against that (which makes both approaches equal in that regard).

Answer (score 2):

Forms authentication is just a mechanism for passing an authentication token from the browser to the server, which serves as the requestor's identity. I take it right now you're using a Session variable to remember the logged in user's information? That is akin to forms authentication because Session state is maintained (in part) through a cookie. Similarly, forms authentication creates a tamper-proof identity token and stores it using a cookie so that when the user makes subsequent requests, the cookie is sent to the server, which says, "Hey, I'm user X." Forms authentication, as it's name says, is just a mechanism for authenticating - that is, identifying - visitors.

For authorization you would typically use URL authorization, which is a mechanism through which you specify in Web.config, These are pages that are (or are not) accessible to certain users (and/or roles). Again, though, URL authorization, as its name implies, is just a mechanism for authorizing users, for determining if a given requestor has the rights to retrieve a certain resource.

So how do you store user information, like username, email, password, and so forth? That's where Membership comes into play. It's an extensible framework for creating and storing and managing user accounts. There's also the Roles system, which is a similarly extensible model for creating roles and associating them with users.

These, then, are the tools and frameworks you should explore: forms authentication, URL authorization, Membership, and Roles. They are complementary technologies and are (usually) used in tandem.

To address you specific questions:

> How easy is it to implement this using Forms Authentication and what advantage does that give over implementing a custom solution.

Forms authentication (and URL auth and Membership and Roles) are pretty easy to implement. There are three primary advantages to using these technologies rather than a custom solution:

1. Using these technologies is more efficient. You don't have to reinvent the wheel, thereby saving you oodles of time.
2. Using these technologies leads to less buggy code. If you implement a custom solution you may have a security hole or bug that you don't catch during testing. Forms auth and URL authorization have both been around since ASP.NET's inception (nearly a decade now) and have been used and "tested in the field" by millions of developers around the world. Membership and Roles have been around for 5-6 years with similar levels of field testing. Obviously, you can't say the same about your custom solution.
3. Using these technologies makes your application more maintainable. If you need to hire a new dev to help on the site, chances are she'll already be familiar with forms auth et al, but would need to spend time to come up to speed with your custom solution.

> I am also concerned with knowing if there would be any advantage when it comes to securing from session hijacking and against spoofing where an attacker could replay requests and impersonate legit users. Would Forms Authentication have any advantage there, or is it only SSL that can secure against that (which makes both approaches equal in that regard).

Forms auth has very tight security (presuming you're using the default settings). The authentication ticket is encrypted and digitally signed and has a time-based expiry built in (to reduce the surface area for replay attacks). I'm not sure your what your current, custom solution uses for identity since you didn't mention it, but I'd wager it's session state. That will be just as "secure." The point is, the identity tokens - the session cookie in your case and the authentication ticket in the case of forms auth - are both secure and can be safely transmitted over the Internet without SSL.

Regardless of what approach you use, however, it is imperative that you SSL protect, at minimum, the sign in page. This is the page where a user enters his credentials. If that page is **not** being accessed over SSL then the user's credentials will be sent over the Internet in plain text.

> would [Membership, Roles, etc.] give me the ability to assign users access to certain pages directly and at the same time through Roles (that group access definition to multiple pages)

URL authorization allows you to lock down an entire page based on the user/role. To grant access to particular features on the page you would have to write your own code/logic.

To learn these technologies, I will, shamelessly, recommend that you check out [my tutorials on website security](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials). There are a total of 15 step-by-step tutorials in both C# and VB with complete, tested, working demo code you can download. They cover the gamut of user account-related scenarios, from forms auth to URL authorization to role-based authorization to creating and managing user accounts.

Here is the URL again: http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials

Happy Programming!

Comment: I have looked at all that, and my questions remain:
1. would that give me the ability to assign users access to certain pages directly and at the same time through Roles (that group access definition to multiple pages)?
2. would that give me the fine grained control of specifying Add/Edit/Delete permissions on every page? 
3. When it comes to security, do I get that there is not much advantage over using my custom approach and that eventually the only real security would be SSL?
Here is a relevant entity:
User_Page
 user_id,
 url,
 can_add,
 can_edit,
 can_delete

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration Scott.
The way I see it from the resources, configuring who can access what is stored in web.config, in a custom solution that would be stored in mapping tables in the db, is that also doable in Forms Authentication and Membership?
Also, do you have some kind of example or sample that implements something similar to what I need (authorizing Add/Edit/Delete features in pages). Thanks

Comment: MSD, you would need to store some sort of tables in the database, yes. These are not part of Membership. I'm afraid I don't have any (or know of any) examples that illustrate how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at asp.net membership provider:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Everything is there and highly customizable